# Docker build fails in apt-get

Tags: docker

I'm getting an error during build. I've seen many similar questions but nothing seems to solve this issue.

I'm running Docker (Version 17.06.0-ce-mac18) on OS X El Capitan.

My `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q git
```

I'm getting Bad Request 400 error from one of git dependencies:

```
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main patch amd64 2.7.1-4ubuntu2.3 [86.4 kB]
Fetched 7619 kB in 5s (1367 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-data_1.6.2-1ubuntu2_all.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q git' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Any explanations or ideas for workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the mirror being used is not reachable at the moment, 
You can try changing mirrors in for ubuntu from your docker file using `sed`.

You can also use ubuntu's mirror protocol, which will fetch mirrors located within your country:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN sed -i -e 's/http:\/\/archive/mirror:\/\/mirrors/' -e 's/\/ubuntu\//\/mirrors.txt/' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q git
```

You can even specify a specific mirror you want to be used in the same way. 
For more information about apt mirrors refer to this [post](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-select-the-fastest-apt-mirror-on-ubuntu-linux)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried few mirrors until an Australian one worked:
`RUN sed -i 's/http:\/\/archive.ubuntu.com\/ubuntu\//http:\/\/ubuntu.mirror.serversaustralia.com.au\/ubuntu\//' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem come from the fact that you are using ubuntu:14.04 which is deprecated (https://askubuntu.com/questions/731891/not-able-to-install-anything-and-update-on-ubuntu-14-10)

Can you try with `FROM ubuntu` ? This will use the latest ubuntu image, which is 16.04.

EDIT: Ubuntu 14.04 is an LTS, so as pointed by @jwodder it should still be supported. I would still try to use the latest LTS (16.04) with `FROM ubuntu` as it might be an easy fix.

Comment: The linked question is about 14.10, while this question is about 14.04, which is still supported until 2019.

Comment: Oh yes, 14.04 is also an LTS so yeah you're right, my bad.
Still I'm curious to know if the issue would persist with the latest image.

Comment: Tried also with `From ubuntu:16.04`, I'm getting different 400 errors `E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sqlite3/libsqlite3-0_3.11.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libe/libedit/libedit2_3.1-20150325-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]`

Comment: That strange, I've tired on my machine and everything is fine.
Can you try to run the same command inside an ubuntu container ? Do `docker run -it ubuntu bash` and then `apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q git`